# Fastest way to get arraylist items in all other arraylists

Tags: java, arraylist, inner-join

I'm looking for a smart and fast way of getting only the values, of multiple arraylists (stored in a hashmap), that are in ALL of the other arraylists.

E.g.
[a] = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
[b] = 1, 3
[c] = 3

Result = 3

What is the fastest way to achieve this in Java?

Comment: You could store each value and its number of occurence in a map - only those with 3 occurences are in the 3 lists.

Comment: you might want to accept a few answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

```
  // assuming you have List<List<?>> lists that is non-empty
  Set<?> result = Sets.newLinkedHashSet(lists.get(0));
  for (int i = 1; i < lists.size(); i++) {
    result.retainAll(ImmutableSet.copyOf(lists.get(i)));
  }

  return result;
```

Comment: Probably the best answer.  This problem only deals with set intersection, so it makes perfect sense.

Comment: @sjr never worked with Google Guava - Could you slightly explain your code

Comment: it initializes a set containing the unique elements of the first list. At the end of each iteration of the loop, `result` contains all the elements in the first through ith list.

Under the covers it uses a HashSet to retrieve elements, so when you do `Sets.intersection`, this will eventually call `contains()` on one of the sets, which is O(1) in HashSet.

Comment: -1.  You don't want to call `Sets.intersection` in a loop like this; the overhead of the set view grows linearly with `lists.size()`.  You'd be better off using a `LinkedHashSet` and `retainAll` for each particular set.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Collections.retainAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#retainAll%28java.util.Collection%29) using the ArrayLists:

```
list1.retainAll(list2);
list1.retainAll(list3);
```

but do bear in mind that you will change the content of `list1`.

Comment: that's a nice solution too but it might be slower than intersection for massive lists. For example if the lists are arraylists then this will be O(n^2) whereas mine should be linear.

Comment: @sjr Yes, but it's also nice that it doesn't use external libraries

Comment: also question asked for "fastest"

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through them, and add any identical ones to a new arraylist.

```
    List commons = new ArrayList();
    for(int i=0; i < list1.size() && i < list2.size(); i++) {
        Object list1val = list1.get(i);
        Object list2val = list2.get(i);
        if((list1val == null && list2val == null) ||
                (list1val != null && list1val.equals(list2val)))
                commons.add(list1val);
    }
}
```